# How to resolve "unmerged: ..." git status?

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I have the following `git status` and I need to get rid of `pluginA` and `pluginB`:

```
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   unmerged:   vendor/plugins/pluginA
#   unmerged:   vendor/plugins/pluginB
```

I have a repository with these branches that are shared between the client and myself:

**master** (client version of the code)
**production** (our production version of the code)
**development** (our development version of the code)

Changes have been made in `master` that we need to start using and I need to leave `production` and `development` alone. I've created a new "merge" branch (based on development) and merged the code from master. Unfortunately it has left us with the two plugin issues above. These were removed in the `master` but are still in the `development` branch. When merging I had messages like:

> CONFLICT (directory/file): There is a directory with name vendor/plugins/pluginA in HEAD. Adding vendor/plugins/pluginA as vendor/plugins/pluginA~master

Since I am trying to get the `master` version, how can I just remove the plugins? Seems like most other deleted files were merged correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got a conflict because git found a **directory** (`vendor/plugins/pluginA` **directory** in `development`) when a **file** was found in merge's remote (`vendor/plugins/pluginA` **file** in `master`).

Since it isn't possible to merge a file with a directory, git makes a copy of the master data in `vendor/plugins/pluginA~master` (to avoid losing data), and leaves you with a conflict that needs to be resolved manually.

Move/rename/delete/copy/edit/whatever those files to get your code to the desired state, then `git add` the changes and `git commit` the conflict resolution.